# PHP: text to image + fit to the block + split text to tokens when two empty lines

Tags: php, html, image, split, preg-split

I have a bunch of files I receive from an HTML form, and I go through them:

```
$img = $_FILES['img'];

function reArrayFiles($file) {
        $file_ary = array();
        $file_count = count($file['name']);
        $file_key = array_keys($file);

        for($i=0;$i<$file_count;$i++) {
            foreach($file_key as $val) {
                $file_ary[$i][$val] = $file[$val][$i];
            }
        }
        return $file_ary;
}

$img_desc = reArrayFiles($img);

foreach($img_desc as $val) {
    if ($val['type'] == 'text/plain') {
        ... ?
    }
}
```

What we need is to:

1) Split the text when there are two empty lines.

I was using `preg_split('#\n#', file_get_contents($val['tmp_name']));`, but it didn't work with '#\n\n\n#'. What do I do to make it work?

Anyway, when we receive an array of strings, what we need is to

2) Fit each of these strings to a 500 x 500 sized block automatically putting linebreaks when needed and save it as an image on a server.

So that it won't look like this:
[Text to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqAGf.png)

Comment: have you tried `explode('\n')`

Comment: OK This worked for (1): $txtarray = str_replace("\r","\n",file_get_contents($val['tmp_name']));
     $txtarray = explode("\n\n\n\n", $txtarray);

Comment: OK. This worked for (2): class.upload.php & $txtfield = chunk_split($txtfield, 50, "\n");. More elegant solutions?

Comment: Oh. For (1): \R matches \n, \r and \r\n also.